# How to scrape website, where I can't prevent login error

Tags: python

I try to scrape website 'https://laboral.pjud.cl/SITLAPORWEB/InicioAplicacionPortal.do', but each time I got the same page with error. I think problem is that I have to authenticate on this website first.
I've tried to create session object and send post request, but nothing seems to change.

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth    

username = 'user'    
password = 'pass'    
scrape_url = 'https://laboral.pjud.cl/SITLAPORWEB/InicioAplicacionPortal.do'    
login_url = 'https://laboral.pjud.cl/SITLAPORWEB/jsp/LoginPortal/LoginPortal.jsp'    
r = requests.get(login_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))    
print(r.text)    
>>>
   <form name="InicioAplicacionForm" method="POST" 
   action="/SITLAPORWEB/InicioAplicacionPortal.do"><INPUT 
   type="hidden" name="FLG_Autoconsulta" value="1"><input 
   type="hidden" name="D0E0F02E" 
   value="764C8AA111F42E621BC10BA16CD8D8B2">
   </form><script>document.InicioAplicacionForm.submit();</script>

login_info = {'username': username,'password': password, "D0E0F02E":"764C8AA111F42E621BC10BA16CD8D8B2"}    
session = requests.session()    
session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)    
url = session.get(url=scrape_url)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')    
print(soup)
```

Comment: As a first step, you can use your favorite browser's developer tools and observe what kind of `POST/GET` requests are done in order to log in.

Comment: I can't solve problem. I try to send POST with Headers and payload from Developer tools, but still error.

Comment: have you tried to use python selenium web driver? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110931/keep-session-after-login-selenium-javascript